# multiple select data in object format

Tags: react-native

I have a multiple select field where I'll be selecting multiple values, but when I am sending that data to the backend it should show in the following format:

```
"data": 
[
    {
        "vehicle_id": "VEH1",
    },
    {
        "vehicle_id": "VEH2",
    },
]
```

but when I am selecting multiple values from drop down I am getting data in an array format:

```
"data":[
    {
     "vehicle_id":["VEH1","VEH2"]
    }
]
```

How can I send data in the format which I have added in the beginning? .

Code:

```
const getSelectedVehices = (selectedvehicles: any[]) => {
    const vehicles: Array<string> = [];
    const items = new Map<string, string>();
    vehicleListData.forEach((item) => {
      items.set(item.vehicleName, item.vehicleAliasId);
    });

    selectedvehicles.forEach((item) => {
      vehicle.push(items.get(item) || '');
    });
    return vehicles;
  };

  const prepareSelectedVehiclesServices = (electedvehicles: any[]) => {
    const vehicles: Array<string> = [];
    const items = new Map<string, string>();
    vehicleListData.forEach((item) => {
      items.set(item.vehicleName, item.vehicleAliasId);
    });

    vehicles.forEach((item) => {
      if (items.has(item)) {
        vehicles.push(items.get(item) || '');
      }
    });
    return vehicles;
  };

<MultiSelect
            items={pickerOptions.vehicleServices}
            onSelectedItemsChange={(Ids: any[]) => {
              const selectedVehiclesServices = getSelectedVehicles(Ids);
              formikData.setFieldValue(`vehicles`, [
                {
                  vehicleAliasId: selectedVehiclesServices,
                },
              ]);
            }}
            selectedItems={{
              selectedItemIdentifiers: prepareSelectedVehiclesServices(
                formikData.values.services || initialServiceValues.services,
              ),
            }}
          ></MultiSelect>
```

the above is the code which I have added.

Answer (score 0):

Just project the array into your new format with `.map()`.  Something like this:

```js
let myData = { "data":[
  {
    "vehicle_id":["VEH1","VEH2"]
  }
]};

let myNewData = { "data": myData.data[0].vehicle_id.map(d => ({
  "vehicle_id": d
}))};

console.log(myNewData);
```

Comment: the solution which you have suggested is not working,  you can check the code which I have written and let me know where I have to make changes in my code.

Comment: @NikitaShah: The code shown in this answer is a runnable code snippet, you can see that it demonstrably projects one format into the other.  In what way did you attempt to apply this in your code?  (The code currently shown in the question makes no use of this answer's suggestion.)  How specifically does that attempt fail?

Comment: I tried to loop inside the formik, but not sure whether I did it in a right way